# Notifications: Ruby FayeClient - Node.js OR Ruby - Redis pub/sub - Node.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, redis, publish-subscribe, faye

I'm in a bit of a dilemma. I have Rails app which also uses Faye for websocket communication with Node.js server (used for chat and some other stuff). We also already use redis for some short lived data.

Now I want to implement some kind of real time notifications which will be stored in redis. I have two options:

- I install faye gem and use faye client to directly send messages. But this required EventMachine. I tend to refuse adding a lot of new unnecessary stuff if it can be avoided.
- I use redis pub/sub. Send data from rails to redis pub/sub and subscribe to the same channel in Node.js which will then publish those messages on faye channels.

Any suggestions on which approach to take? Or do you maybe have better solutions in mind?